# Batch file to calculate entities in various text files

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with many Text files enclosed. These text files contain the following info:

```
       Entity                   Details 

     Camera XYZ          31 RTP packet(s) have been lost
     Camera YYZ          141 RTP packet(s) have been lost
     Camera YYY          3 RTP packet(s) have been lost
     Camera YYY          100 RTP packet(s) have been lost
```

I'm looking to do the following:

1) Run a batch file which will calculate the total number of  " X RTP packet(s) have been lost"

2) Run a batch file which will calculate the total number of  " X RTP packet(s) have been lost" per Entity. (eg. Camera YYY = 103 RTP Packets Lost)

Any help will be great !

Comment: Are the entities always cameras? Or only two words? Is the format always in that form, i.e. fixed-width columns?

Comment: Entities are various camera names so they vary in size and number of characters.

Comment: Yes they are fixed-width columns.

Is there any way I can chat with you on MSN or something to better desscribe what Im trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

While I wait on you answering the questions in the comment, here a PowerShell version if you can use it:

```
gc *.txt | ?{$_ -match 'lost'} | %{
    $null = $_ -match '\s+(.+?)\s{2,}(\d+)'
    New-Object PSObject -Prop @{ Entity = $Matches[1]; Count = [int]$Matches[2]}
} | group Entity | %{
    "$($_.Name) = $(($_.Group | select -exp Count | measure -sum).Sum) RTP packets lost"
}
```

It's vastly more complicated in a batch file, hence the questions.

Comment: The questions were irrelevant for this answer, so it still stands. However, it depends on that you can use PowerShell, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Below is a link to an example text(log) file.

http://www.megaupload.com/?d=N194AKD1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- `XYZ`, `YYZ`, `YYY` etc. are single words,
- the value in question is always the third 'word' on the line,
- same entities are grouped together,

you could try something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN (D:\Path\To\Files\*.txt) DO (
  SET camera=
  SET totalcnt=0
  FOR /F "tokens=2,3" %%A IN (%%F) DO CALL :process %%A %%B
  CALL :process "" 0
  CALL ECHO Total for file %%F: %%totalcnt%%
)
GOTO :EOF

:process
IF "%camera%" == "%1" GOTO continue
IF NOT "%camera%" == "" ECHO Total RTP packets for Camera %camera%: %cnt%
SET cnt=0
SET camera=%1

:continue
SET /A cnt+=%2
SET /A totalcnt+=%2
```

Comment: And that's why I asked my questions in the comment. Sadly it's not that easy.

Comment: Did you have a look at the file I uploaded?

Comment: Joey it will be awesome if you can help me, is there any way we can chat?

Comment: I have now. And I agree with Joey, yours is not an easy problem for a batch script.

Comment: So can you give me any sort of direction? maybe I can describe it better in a chat session?? sorry for acting desperate here...

Comment: @Sam: Is that example typical? Have all the logs got the same format?

Comment: The format turns out not very consistent. It looked more promising at first. Now I'm not very sure, but maybe there still could be some way of solving this. I'm trying a couple of things now. If you like, we could further discuss it on MSN (I'm *andriy_tm@hotmail.com* there).

Comment: I added you on MSN, when will you be on?